# How to make form with many query PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

How to make FORM with many query from input in php and mysql, should i only use query or use many condition to make the final query, here's the example of the form:

[image]

maybe like this

```
SELECT * FROM aset WHERE lokasi= .. OR jenis=.. OR merk=.. OR tanggal=..
```

how to skip the one of the WHERE clause if the input in FORM is NULL?

Thankyou!

Comment: sorry, it's not clear what you are asking

Comment: maybe it's a `LIKE` in your query that you are searching for?

Comment: do you want the filter to be additionally (so if user types a 'lokasi' and a 'jenis' - should it match both? should only match kindof? should match either or?

Comment: so here's example
condition 1:
lokasi, merk, jenis, tanggal are filled with data, and then the query is SELECT * FROM aset WHERE lokasi= .. OR jenis=.. OR merk=.. OR tanggal=..
condition 2:
only lokasi merk filled with data, and the query is SELECT * FROM aset WHERE lokasi= .. OR merk=.. 
Thanks!

Comment: so there you go! just check what param is set/greater than '' and construct your query!

Comment: is there any, way to skip the WHERE clause in mysql? skipped because the input from one of the condition is null

Comment: you can do a `where 1=2` per default and then add ` OR x=input1` for each input if filled in. (or `where 1=1` if the other conditions should be `AND`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if the field is given/has any value first and then add it to the query, so you can pass the query with only provided fields using the append "=." operator to add.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM aset";

if($_POST['lokasi'] != ''}{

 $query =. "WHERE lokasi ='something'";

}

 if($_POST['jenis'] != ''}{

    if (strpos($query, "lokasi") !== false) //if lokasi exists in the query then add AND
    {
      $query =. " AND WHERE jenis ='something'";

    } else {

    $query =. " WHERE jenis ='something'";

    }

}
```

Comment: yup thanks, but in mysql, is there could skip the WHERE if the condition is NULL?

Comment: yes for example if you click on the "search" button without any values in the 4 fields, then the query will select all rows from "aset" table because the query will only contain "SELECT * FROM aset";

Comment: yup, i mean skip in the query, example : WHERE lokasi = SKIP or something, so we have only to make 1 query without making many condition in php

Comment: yes I understand, you mean if only "lokasi" field is given and the rest 3 of them empty, then the query should only have WHERE lokasi = 'something' right?

Comment: you cannot do WHERE lokasi = SKIP, Rather you have to build the query based on the condition

Comment: yuppp you're right, i wonder if we can solve this with only one query, is there any SQL statement that skip the parameter? :D

Comment: you are welcome, yes unfortunately, >< cannot do it in one line . But this answer should do exactly what you are looking for :D. cheers!

Comment: It's much better to add the conditions to an array, then `implode` the array together with any required `AND` separators. If the array is empty you can skip the `WHERE` clause altogether. Keep in mind this is re-inventing the wheel, any decent ORM already does this. Consider using [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), 
[Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or 
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) instead of your own hand-rolled solution.

Comment: Mikethetechy josss :D |
tadman yup thanks you're right, this is what exactly i lookin for now

Answer (score 0):

You should or simply set your table column to DEFAULT NULL wherein everytime you insert record to the table, if there's a skip field in the form, it will still insert the query to the table.

For example when you create a table.

```
create table sample(id int(11) not null auto_increment,sample_column_1 varchar(255) default null,sample_column_2 varchar(255) default null,primary key(id));
```

Comment: Why does searching require creating a whole other table?